What do Hindus do about byproducts of beef in everyday things? Should we assume what we buy doesnt have it or should we avoid it to stay on safe side?
In USA lots of brands of sugar, napkins, plates, cups, etc have byproducts of beef in them and most Hindus don’t know about it so they might serve it in Restaurants without knowing
Also plastic bags/wrapping (made outside Bharat/India) also have byproducts of beef so having anything shipped online would also become a problem because of plastic wrapping
What do the Shastras say that Hindus should do in this case? Do we have to stop going to Restaurants and buying clothes online to stay on the safer side or are we allowed to assume that what we are buying is not made of byproducts of beef?

There's no way to avoid such kinds of paap other than being careful as much as possible. In the olden times, people would not travel outside their village due to these kinds of problems which would reduce one's capacity for tapasya. Not much can be done except humbly surrendering to God (sharanagati). अहं त्वां सर्वपापेभ्यो मोक्षयिष्यामि मा श‍ुच: (I'll deliver you from all paap. Do not fear. BG 18.66)

@Harihara also I have 2 specific questions that might be easier to answer - based off of what the Shastras say if the plates at a restaurant have things like tallow or glycerin in them and it touches the food would it become like eating beef itself or no? Also if they give you napkins with tallow/glycerin in them would it be my Sin or the owner’s Sin because we are not specifically trying to eat beef?

It is said that all those involved in killing, consenting the killing, helping the killing, carrying, selling, buying, cooking and eating the meat of an animal are equally sinful as the killing of that animal. There'll be some degree of sins for the situations you've described. They would also be reduced to the extent of the intensity of thr spiritual activities performed.

@Harihara sorry in this case I am not talking about eating something with byproducts. right now I am specifically talking about if the plate is made out of byproducts but I am only taking the food and not the plate so if a plastic (with glycerin) plate touches the food would that make the food turn Impure and equal to eating beef or is it still separate and would it not count as eating beef because I still didn’t order beef?

@Mahadeva That won't be the same as the papa of consuming beef for sure. The food will be impure until it is offered to the Lord as a sacrifice (bhuñjate te tv aghaṁ pāpā..BG 3.13).

Kannappa Nāyanār(கண்ணப்ப நாயனார்) was one of the 63 Nāyanmārs holy Saivite saints, the staunch devotees of Lord Shiva, who offered Lord Shiva with meat. Bhagavan Shiva happily consumed the offer because what mattered most was Kannappa's pure Bakthi(devotion) and nothing else.
Sins committed knowingly for good cause will never yield bad karma. Similarly sins committed unknowingly too will not cause bad karma.
Since this is Kali Yuga, wherever we live (whether USA or India), we should learn to live with the prevailing situation. However, best thing to uphold is to avoid making sins consciously.

Sorry for asking late but specifically going based off of Hindu Law would plates/cups/etc with byproducts touching the food become the same as eating beef or no?

We use foot wears/Belts made on skins of different animals. How can we ensure that the skin is not from a cow? No way, but still we all have been using such items. My answer to your question is, in my opinion, serving  food in plates/cups/etc made on beef can’t be considered tantamount to eating beef. Just remember, this is not ancient times but Kali Yuga!
